# PyQT5 development

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5

I am developing a GUI app called duplication finder. What it does is that if a user types or pates a bunch of names, it finds which names are duplicated and outputs the names without duplication and sorts in alphabetical order.

Now, I want to develop this even further since this one was only 0.0 version.

1) When I resize the window, input and output boxes and the button sticks in the same position with the same size. I want them to resize and relocate depending on the size of the window.

2) I want the placeholder text to be bigger and align in the center of the text box.

3) My closeEvent function is not working. I want to ask the user if they really want to exit out.

4) Lastly, I cant get the sub menues in the file menu work. "New" should clear out all the text in the boxes (input and output) basically restart the app. and exit button in the File menu should ask the same question from number 3 above.

I have try to research a lot but these are the only questions I was not able to figure out.

```
import sys
import re
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMessageBox

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("Duplication Finder")
        MainWindow.resize(919, 728)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.Enter_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.Enter_button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(380, 330, 151, 51))
        self.Enter_button.setObjectName("Enter_button")
        self.Text_box = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget, placeholderText="Please insert Text")
        self.Text_box.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 30, 881, 271))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.Text_box.setFont(font)
        self.Text_box.setObjectName("Text_box")
        self.Result_box = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.Result_box.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 410, 881, 271))
        self.Result_box.setObjectName("Result_box")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 919, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menu = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menu.setObjectName("menu")
        self.menuEdit = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuEdit.setObjectName("menuEdit")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.actionNew = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionNew.setObjectName("actionNew")
        self.actionExit = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionExit.setObjectName("actionExit")
        self.menu.addAction(self.actionNew)
        self.menu.addAction(self.actionExit)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menu.menuAction())
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuEdit.menuAction())

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Duplication Finder v0.0"))
        self.Enter_button.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Type"))
        self.menu.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "File"))
        self.menuEdit.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Edit"))
        self.actionNew.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "New"))
        self.actionExit.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Exit"))

    def closeEvent(self, QCloseEvent):
        ans = QMessageBox.question(self, "Exit", "Do you want to Exit?",
                                   QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No, QMessageBox.No)
        if ans == QMessageBox.Yes:
            QCloseEvent.accept()
        else:
            QCloseEvent.ignore()





class MyApp(Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, dialog):
        Ui_MainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(dialog)

        self.Enter_button.clicked.connect(self.duplication)

    def duplication(self):
        text = self.Text_box.toPlainText()
        text = re.split(", |-|  |,", text)  # split based on the delimeter in the argument.
        text = [s.strip() for s in text]  # remove all the leading spaces in each elements of the list
        name = list(filter(None, text))  # drop all the empty elements and put them in a list

        i = 0

        names = []
        remove = []

        # go through all the elements in the list and see if they are duplicated.
        while i < len(name):
            each_name = name[i].strip()
            if each_name.startswith(("*", "-")):
                continue  # straight to next line
            if each_name not in names:
                names.append(each_name)
            elif each_name in names:
                remove.append(each_name)

            i += 1

        # sort the list and send "무명' to the very end.
        sort_names = sorted(names, key=lambda x: (x.startswith("무명"), x))
        sort_names = ", ".join(sort_names)

        output_string = f'\n\nDuplication: {(sorted(remove))}\n\nTotal of {len(remove)}duplications are are removed, Total of {len(names)}people are printed.\n\n {sort_names}'

        self.Result_box.setText(output_string)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    dialog = QMainWindow()

    prog = MyApp(dialog)

    dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: We cannot do your homework.   Read the doc

Comment: Please, avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it:

```
import sys
import re
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QMessageBox


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("반복 단어 찾기")
        MainWindow.resize(919, 728)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.Enter_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.Enter_button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(380, 330, 151, 51))
        self.Enter_button.setObjectName("Enter_button")
        self.Text_box = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget, placeholderText="Please insert Text")
        self.Text_box.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 30, 881, 271))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.Text_box.setFont(font)
        self.Text_box.setObjectName("Text_box")
        self.Result_box = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.Result_box.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 410, 881, 271))
        self.Result_box.setObjectName("Result_box")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 919, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menu = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menu.setObjectName("menu")
        self.menuEdit = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuEdit.setObjectName("menuEdit")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.actionNew = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionNew.setObjectName("actionNew")

### 4.1
        self.actionNew.triggered.connect(self.clearTextEdit)

        self.actionExit = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionExit.setObjectName("actionExit")

### 4.2        
        self.actionExit.triggered.connect(self.close)

        self.menu.addAction(self.actionNew)
        self.menu.addAction(self.actionExit)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menu.menuAction())
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuEdit.menuAction())

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Duplication Finder v0.0"))
        self.Enter_button.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Type"))
        self.menu.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "File"))
        self.menuEdit.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Edit"))
        self.actionNew.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "New"))
        self.actionExit.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Exit"))

#    def closeEvent(self, QCloseEvent):
#        ans = QMessageBox.question(self, "Exit", "Do you want to Exit?",
#                                   QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No, QMessageBox.No)
#        if ans == QMessageBox.Yes:
#            QCloseEvent.accept()
#        else:
#            QCloseEvent.ignore()


class MyApp(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):    # +++ QMainWindow
#    def __init__(self, dialog):
#        Ui_MainWindow.__init__(self)
#        self.setupUi(dialog)
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

### 2        
        self.Text_box.setStyleSheet('font-size: 24pt;')
        self.Text_box.setPlaceholderText("Please insert Text")

        self.Enter_button.clicked.connect(self.duplication)

### 1   I want them to resize and relocate depending on the size of the window.       
        grid = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        grid.addWidget(self.Text_box,     0, 0) 
        grid.addWidget(self.Enter_button, 1, 0)
        grid.addWidget(self.Result_box,   2, 0)


    def duplication(self):
        text = self.Text_box.toPlainText()
        text = re.split(", |-|  |,", text)  # split based on the delimeter in the argument.
        text = [s.strip() for s in text]  # remove all the leading spaces in each elements of the list
        name = list(filter(None, text))  # drop all the empty elements and put them in a list

        i = 0

        names = []
        remove = []

        # go through all the elements in the list and see if they are duplicated.
        while i < len(name):
            each_name = name[i].strip()
            if each_name.startswith(("*", "-")):
                continue  # straight to next line
            if each_name not in names:
                names.append(each_name)
            elif each_name in names:
                remove.append(each_name)

            i += 1

        # sort the list and send "무명' to the very end.
        sort_names = sorted(names, key=lambda x: (x.startswith("무명"), x))
        sort_names = ", ".join(sort_names)

#        output_string = f'\n\n중복된 사람: {(sorted(remove))}\n\n총 {len(remove)}명이 중복되어 삭제 되었고, 총 {len(names)}명이 출력되었습니다.\n\n {sort_names}'
        output_string = '''\n\n중복된 사람: {}
            \n총 {}명이 중복되어 삭제 되었고, 총 {}명이 출력되었습니다.
            \n {}'''.format(sorted(remove), len(remove), len(names), sort_names)

        self.Result_box.setText(output_string)

### 4.1
    def clearTextEdit(self):
        self.Text_box.setText("")
        self.Result_box.setText("")  

### 3, 4.2
    def closeEvent(self, QCloseEvent):
        ans = QMessageBox.question(self, "Exit", "Do you want to Exit?",
                                   QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No, QMessageBox.No)
        if ans == QMessageBox.Yes:
            QCloseEvent.accept()
        else:
            QCloseEvent.ignore()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
### 2    
    app.setFont(QtGui.QFontDatabase().font("Monospace", "Regular", 23))    

#    dialog = QMainWindow()
#    prog = MyApp(dialog)
    prog = MyApp()

#    dialog.show()
    prog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]